# Parallax js active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am playing around with a [parallax prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/KBFsk/) and I need to assign a class active to each slide that slides up so that I can call some functions when the particular slide is active.

```
var $window = $(window),
    speed = 0.2;

function update(){ 

    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
        container = $('.container'),
        containerHeight = container.height(),
        updateTop = parseInt(containerHeight) - scrolled * speed;

    $('.js-background-2').css('top', updateTop+'px');
    $('.js-background-2 h2').css('margin-top', (scrolled/2)+'px');

    $('.js-background-3').css('top', (updateTop*2)+'px');
    $('.js-background-3 h2').css('margin-top', (scrolled/3)+'px');

    $('.js-background-4').css('top', (updateTop*3)+'px');
    $('.js-background-4 h2').css('margin-top', (scrolled/4)+'px');

}; 

$window.bind('scroll', update);
```

Comment: You'd need to decide where your breakpoint is. I.e, if a slide/container has `100px` remaining left until it *meets* the window top, `.addClass()` to that relevant container in view.

Comment: in terms of code how would you "decide if the div has 100px left untill it meets the window top"? thanks

Comment: bit like this! Still a littl' buggy though: http://jsfiddle.net/GGLf5/